# Stopping log script from being accessed by multiple threads

Tags: python, logging, process, thread-safety, handler

I have a module called `myLog.py` which is being accessed by multiple other modules in a project. The `myLog.py` module has two handlers: `file_handler` that inputs logs into file and `stream_handler` that outputs logs to a console. For modules where no threading is occurring i.e `myLog.py` is only being accessed by a single process the logs are being inserted properly but for modules where threading is being implemented i.e `myLog.py` is being accessed by multiple processes at the same time I am getting multiple logs of the same line being inserted in my `log_file.txt`.

While going through logging documentation I found out that logging module is `thread_safe` but my implementation says things differently. How should I initialize the function `setLogger()` in `myLog.py` such that if it gets accessed by multiple threads at the same time it gives the correct output?

```
#myLog.py

#setup of logger
def setLogger(logfile_name = "log_file.txt"):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile_name)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    return logger
```

So suppose for example it is being accessed by a module called parser.py which implements threading then the log statements get printed out in a very random duplicated fashion.

```
#parser.py

import threading
import myLog

logger = myLog.setLogger()

class investigate(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, section, file, buffer, args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.section = section
        self.file = file
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.args = args
        self.sig = self.pub = None
        self.exc = None

    def run(self):
        aprint("Starting section %d file %d" % (self.section, self.file))
        self.exc = None
        try:
            self.sign()
            aprint("Done section %d file %d" % (self.section, self.file))
        except:
            self.exc = sys.exc_info()

    def sign(self):
        self.sig, self.pub = sign_hsm(self.buffer, self.args)
        if self.sig is None or self.pub is None:
            raise Exception("Empty signing result")

    def store(self, bot):
        sec = filter(lambda x: x.type == self.section, bot.sections)[0]
        if self.file == 0xFF:
            signature = sec.signature
        else:
            signature = sec.files[self.file].signature
        signature.sig = self.sig
        signature.pub = self.pub

    def join(self, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.join(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if self.exc:
            msg = "Thread '%s' threw an exception: %s" % (self.getName(), self.exc[1])
            new_exc = Exception(msg)
            raise new_exc.__class__, new_exc, self.exc[2]

def PrintVersion():
    logger.info("This is output.")

print_lock = threading.RLock()
def aprint(*args, **kwargs):
    if verbosityLevel > 0:
        with print_lock:
            return logger.info(*args, **kwargs)


def multipleTimes():
    logger.info("Multiple times.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PrintVersion()
    for investigate in investigations:
       investigate.start()
      .......
      .......
      .......
    logger.info("This gets repeated")
    multipleTimes()
```

So since multiple threads are trying to access the `setLogger()` I get `logger.info()` outputs such as:

```
This is output.
This is output.
This is output.
This is output.
This is output.
This gets repeated.
This gets repeated.
This gets repeated.
Multiple times.
Multiple times.
Multiple times.
Multiple times.
Multiple times.
Multiple times.
```

What I should be getting:

```
This is output.
This gets repeated.
Multiple times.
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @martineau But this is more of a conceptual question than a question which should be reproduced by the person for solution. I do have the module which is trying to access this module myLog.py through multiple parallel processes but reproducing it here minimally will be very hard.

Comment: The real code isn't needed, just something _minimal_ that illustrates the problem — so it's not just "comceptual" and folks will have something to use to test their solutions. The docs imply it shouldn't happen, so provide some code showing that in fact it does.

Comment: @martineau I hope the new edit helps

Comment: Looks promising but it's not runnable — for example, what's `aprint()`?

Comment: @martineau I have added aprint() function. Sorry the module parser.py is not mine and its written by someone else so it is hard for me to decipher it completely. However, myLog.py is mine and I know that a lot of instances of parser.py file tries to access myLog.py at the same time which is causing the issue. So all the functions PrintVersion() and multipleTimes() gets executed multiple times for different threads. So basically if __name__ == "__main__": gets executed multiple times and I have mentioned the thread class investigate which is doing that. Please help me change myLog.,py